# Filter a list within a list using linq in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to filter a list that is inside a list in C# using Linq

```
 var  catalogs = await _context.MerchantCatalogs
            .Include(x => x.merchantDiscounts)
            .ToListAsync();
```

I have a list of items inside the item there is a list of discounts and I need to get the discount for the specific user

MerchantCatalogs has a field called discount which has a discount type either (1,2)
and I need to only get the discount within the list which has a type of 2

```
public class MerchantCatalogs
{
    int ID;
    public ICollection<MerchantDiscount> merchantDiscounts { get; set; }
}
public class MerchantDiscount
{
    int id;
    int type;
}
```

how do I get the list which has an inner list of MerchantDiscount = 1

Comment: What does it mean? You only want outer results if the inner list is only `type == 2`, or do you want all outer, together with only inners if the `type == 2`/an empty inner if no inner has a type of 2? For data of: `{ID=1,merchantDiscounts=[{id=1,type=1}]}, {ID=2,merchantDiscounts=[{id=2,type=2}]}, {ID=3,merchantDiscounts=[{id=3,type=1},{id=4,type=2}]}` what is the result?

Comment: I want all the outer results with the inner of type 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Where clausule to filter the results:

```
var  catalogs = await _context.MerchantCatalogs
        .Include(x => x.merchantDiscounts.Where(discount => discount.type == 2))
        .ToListAsync();
```

And if you only want the Merchants that HAVE any discount of type 2

```
var  catalogs = await _context.MerchantCatalogs
        .Include(x => x.merchantDiscounts.Where(discount => discount.type == 2))
        .Where(merchant=> merchant.merchantDiscounts.Any())
        .ToListAsync();
```